# mongo $unwind and sum individually the third value of returning and new visitors

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

From the following document example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("528e4798bfa9782c078b4662"),
    "query" : {
        "start-date" : ISODate("2013-11-19T00:00:00Z"),
        "end-date" : ISODate("2013-11-20T00:00:00Z"),
        "ids" : "ga:69564270",
        "dimensions" : "ga:visitorType,ga:visitCount",
        "metrics" : [
            "ga:organicSearches"
        ]
    },
    "columnHeaders" : [
        {
            "name" : "ga:visitorType",
            "columnType" : "DIMENSION",
            "dataType" : "STRING"
        },
        {
            "name" : "ga:visitCount",
            "columnType" : "DIMENSION",
            "dataType" : "STRING"
        },
        {
            "name" : "ga:organicSearches",
            "columnType" : "METRIC",
            "dataType" : "INTEGER"
        }
    ],
    "totalsForAllResults" : {
        "ga:organicSearches" : 119
    },
    "rows" : [
        [
            "New Visitor",
            "1",
            100
        ],
        [
            "Returning Visitor",
            "11",
            1
        ],
        [
            "Returning Visitor",
            "2",
            10
        ],
        [
            "New Visitor",
            "3",
            4
        ],
        [
            "Returning Visitor",
            "4",
            1
        ],
        [
            "Returning Visitor",
            "5",
            1
        ],
        [
            "New Visitor",
            "6",
            1
        ],
        [
            "New Visitor",
            "8",
            1
        ]
    ],
    "query_name" : "GA Organic Traffic Metric",
    "profile_id" : 666,
    "retrieve_date" : ISODate("2013-11-21T17:49:12Z")
}
```

How can I use the mongo aggregate framework:

## 1 To group and project the sum of: New visitors by "query.start-date"

## 2 To group and project the sum of: Returning Visitors by "query.start-date"

Currently, as You can see "ga:organicSearches" I am having the sum of both, but I need each type of visitors individually, something like "ga:organicSearchesReturningVisitors" and "ga:organicSearchesNewVisitors".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is each document guaranteed to cover one day?  Or are some of them possibly spanning multiple days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are okay doing two aggregations, you can do it this way (I'm assuming each document represents one day):

1. New visitors:

   ```
   db.visitors.aggregate({$unwind:"$rows"},
       {$match:{"rows.0":"New Visitor"}},
       {$unwind:"$rows"},
       {$match:{"rows":{$type:1}}},
       {$group:{_id:"$query.start-date",newVisitorsSum:{$sum:"$rows"}}});

   { "_id" : ISODate("2013-11-19T00:00:00Z"), "newVisitorsSum" : 106 }
   ```
2. Returning visitors:

   ```
   db.visitors.aggregate({$unwind:"$rows"},
       {$match:{"rows.0":"Returning Visitor"}},
       {$unwind:"$rows"}, 
       {$match:{"rows":{$type:1}}}, 
       {$group:{_id:"$query.start-date",retVisitorsSum:{$sum:"$rows"}}});

   { "_id" : ISODate("2013-11-19T00:00:00Z"), "retVisitorsSum" : 13 }
   ```